# How to restore placeholder text when TextField is cleared

Tags: text, swiftui, placeholder, restore

I'm having an issue restoring the placeholder text on a TextField when the TextField has been cleared.

Are there any less hacky ways of restoring the text other than what I've found here?

[Clearing SwiftUI TextField will not restore placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59560138/clearing-swiftui-textfield-will-not-restore-placeholder)

Cheers,
Oliver

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Fixed in iOS 15

*consider below for old versions support only

---

As I wrote in that other topic it is current SwiftUI defect, so for now only workaround is possible.

Here is a simple one that works for me (I prefer this approach because it remains valid even after some fixes/changes in the area):

```
@State private var text: String = ""
@State private var refresh = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField("Placeholder" + (refresh ? "" : " "), text: $text)
        Divider()
        Button("Clear") {
            self.text = ""
            self.refresh.toggle() // << force refresh placeholder explicitly
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Having same trouble, but not in SwiftUI, so how do you simply clear a textField such that it goes back to the placeholder??  Seems SO simple, yet Apple provides zero guidance here.